# Chemical Formation Of A Virus

Tags: chemical-biology

Many articles and books classify virus as a non living thing which only replicate itself inside a living host, yet some describe virus as a living organism. Virus was first discovered on the year 1892 by Dmitry Ivanovsky and Martinus Beijerinck. Since the year it was discovered, virus has different source of it's formation.

I am curious about the formation of a virus. Is there a chemical reaction that will make a virus to became a 'virus'? What are the chemicals responsible for the formation of virus? Are the temperature and geography affect the formation of a virus? On the other hand, what chemical properties classify virus as a non living thing?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: We cannot give you a microbiology 101 lecture here. Try to read up e.g. on wikipedia how viruses work, then come back if you have specific questions. But I think biology.SE would be a better place to ask. And no, there is no single chemical reaction that makes a virus. A virus is simply a piece of freefloating DNA, and every virus type was obviously first produced by some malfunctioning cell.

Comment: @Karl. Thank You. I posted the question here because I am curious whether a virus is produced via chemical reaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, viruses are formed in other cells by the chemical processes of those cells. [Viruses "hijack" the cell's means for reproducing viral RNA or DNA and for the protein coat of the virus.](https://www.immunology.org/public-information/bitesized-immunology/pathogens-and-disease/virus-replication)

Second, define "alive"... there is some argument on whether a virus is living or not, so that depends on your definition.

Third, what does geography have to do with viral reproduction?

Try to focus your question so you can get a useful answer.

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik. I am just curious about the geography, whether it affects the host of the virus, which will also the affect the formation of the virus itself.

Comment: @HYDR0GEN You are aware there are very many different viruses and virus types? That every species in flora and fauna has their own selection of viral maladies?

Comment: @Karl. Yes, I am aware of that.